# Plugin in the checkout page doesn't works until i refresh the page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, plugin

So i'm using Magento 2.3 and i'm creating a **Plugin to execute After Save Addres Information**, that **should execute** when this button were clicked:[image: button]

So, actually it works, **but not at all**, it redirects to the next page**(Review & Payments)** but the information that i'm updating with the plugin **doesn't updates**, it just updates **when i refresh** the page.

> di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
      <plugin name="get_shipping_info" 
type="Mageplaza\Pontos\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Am i using the correct Plugin? should i use an Observer ?